# Ignition SDK Gateway configuration shows path, not string

Tags: ignition

I am trying to program a MODULE for the Ignition SDK but I am running into problems with the paths of the strings in the .properties file not working properly.

I have a file called

```
ProfileSettings.properties
```

and one called

```
ProfileSettings.java
```

In .properties file, I have the following strings:

```
Category.Settings=Connection
ConnectionString.Name=Connection String
ConnectionString.Desc=Connection String for the IoT Hub device
MaxTime.Name=Maximum time 
MaxTime.Desc=The time spent 
MaxMessages.Name=Maximum to collect
MaxMessages.Desc=will be collected
```

and in the .java file, I have reference to the strings by using

```
public static final StringField connectionString = new StringField(META, "ConnectionString");
public static final IntField maxTime = new IntField(META, "MaxTime");
public static final IntField maxMessages = new IntField(META, "MaxMessages");
Category CONNECTION_CATEGORY = new Category("ProfileSettings.Category.Connection", 1001)
        .include(connectionString, maxTime, maxMessages);
```

but when I load the module into the gateway and look at the configuration page, I get `¿ProfileSettings.ConnectionString.Name?` where it shows question marks 
around the path and not the actual text needed for all the strings

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the complete field names?

`public static final StringField connectionString = new StringField(META, "ConnectionString.Name");`

Or possibly

`public static final StringField connectionStringName = new StringField(META, "ConnectionString.Name");`

It would be helpful to have more information about what and where those files are from. Is the .properties file or properties.java something you wrote or is that something that comes as part of the SDK?